# I've added a google analytics segment to block two different types of bot traffic. Unique pageviews are now showing differently on different GA pages

Tags: google-analytics

I've added a google analytics segment to block two different types of bot traffic. Unique pageviews are now showing differently on different GA pages, one condition excludes a whole country (obscure) we do no business with but were getting bot traffic from. Another stops trafficbot.life spam (see here for context [https://www.analytics-toolkit.com/referrer-spam/trafficbot.life/#:~:text=life%22%20or%20page%20then%20your,spam%2C%20language%20spam%2C%20etc.](https://www.analytics-toolkit.com/referrer-spam/trafficbot.life/#:%7E:text=life%22%20or%20page%20then%20your,spam%2C%20language%20spam%2C%20etc.)) Now that this segment with the two conditions is active I am getting different unique pageviews when I look in either: Behavior > Site Content > All Pages and the 'Overview page' that also shows unique pageviews. If I remove the segment I see no difference in the unique pageview numbers between these two screens.

Another piece to add is that comparing YOY numbers with the segment on vs not comparing YOY gives me different figures again. This doesn't happen either if the segment isn't enabled.

These are the segment conditions: [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show some screenshot of report, pls

Comment: Thanks, I just added them. One with the extra custom segment, one without and then the 'Overview' report from the behavior section. They all show different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have reached the sampling threshold. Default reports are not subject to sampling. However, above a certain **threshold of sessions** (*in Analytics Standard it is 500k sessions at the property level for the date range you are using*) by **applying a segment** you required an ad-hoc queries so your data are subject to the thresholds for **sampling**, see here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

What you can do is query two shorter periods.